# API Import in APIM using Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to import API using swagger.json file using Azure Pipeline. I have added a Azure CLI Task Version 2. Selected Script Type as Powershell Core.

In the inline script I have used below commands

```
$apiMgmtContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServiceName $ServiceName

$api = Get-AzApiManagementApi -Context $apiMgmtContext -Name $ApiName
```

The first one is working fine. But the second line of code is throwing error.

Below is the error I get:

[image]

I have searched this error Status Code : CloseError But no solid information on the same. I tried to Install few powershell modules for Azure Api , still it gives the same error.

Comment: @starball I have made the changes. Please help

Comment: You didn't transcribe the error message yet! Also, I personally don't have the subject-matter-expertise to help you. [Wait patiently](/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: @starball I am sorry but its difficult to get the error message from the terminal as it is prohibited to copy from there in our organization. Kindly let me know if anything else I can do

Comment: If you can't copy from your organization's material, then how about you create a [mre] on your personal computer and provide that [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I have tried with the below mentioned Azure APIM PowerShell Commands to get the API details from the Azure APIM Instance and got expected results:***

```
$ApimResource = New-AzApiManagement -Name "pravusapim1205" -ResourceGroupName "pravutestrg" -Location "West US" -Organization "Contoso" -AdminEmail "admin@contoso.com"
$ApimResourceDetails = Get-AzApiManagement -Name "pravusapim1205" -ResourceGroupName "pravutestrg"
$ApimResourceDetails

$ApiMgmtContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "pravutestrg" -ServiceName "pravusapim1205"
$ApiName = "Echo API"
$api = Get-AzApiManagementApi -Context $apiMgmtContext -Name $ApiName
$api
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:** [GitHub Doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/src/ApiManagement/ApiManagement/help/New-AzApiManagementContext.md) on APIM PS Commands.